# Property of being a tautology

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In logic, a statement that is *tautological* is true in every interpretation. A synonym for this is that it is *logically valid*. Such a statement is also called a *tautology*.

- You verify that a statement is *valid* by checking its *validity*, meaning it is a **...** .
- You verify that a statement is *tautological* by checking its **...**, meaning it is a *tautology*.

What words should go where the ellipses are? I'd propose:

- You verify that a statement is *valid* by checking its *validity*, meaning it is a **validship**.
- You verify that a statement is *tautological* by checking its **tautologicity**, meaning it is a *tautology*.

... but these don't seem to exist.

---

**Edit:** Apparently, it was a massive mistake to provide context for this single-word request, and all hope seems lost for getting a linguistically oriented response. Commenters seem to get hung up on specific semantics, whilst my question is about any words that are formed similar to "tautology" and "valid". Take "oncology", "topology", "phonology" and "vapid", "rapid", "fluid" ... We do not need to analyse the deep meaning of words for there to be standard derivative rules; knowing the pronunciation is likely sufficient for a native.

I *know* that the word "valid" is widely used to describe the construction of arguments -- I have Google and Wikipedia too. I *also know* that in my computer science programme at university, I've had more than one course where "logically valid formulas" are exactly synonymous with "tautological formulas". I'm not the only one who has been taught that "valid" is not just applicable to an argument, but also to formulas: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula) [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4095217/the-undecidability-of-validity-and-satisfiability-of-first-order-logic) [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099531/how-to-verify-satisfialibility-in-a-model-confusions-with-g%C3%B6dels-completeness?noredirect=1&lq=1) [list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49445/a-technique-for-deciding-satisfiability-in-fragments-of-first-order-logic?rq=1) [of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440752/satisfiability-and-validity-in-first-order-logic?rq=1) [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617263/validity-of-first-order-formulae-with-free-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1) [sources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184467/show-that-the-decision-problem-for-implication-is-solvable-if-and-only-if-the-de) [treating](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995882912426) [validity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813310/the-entscheidungsproblem-decision-problem-for-modal-logic?rq=1) [synonymous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976552/how-does-modal-logic-differ-from-ordinary-predicate-logic?rq=1) [to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394544/is-kripke-relational-possible-world-semantics-the-special-case-of-the-the-set-se?rq=1) [tautological](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004349/g%C3%B6dels-completeness-theorem-and-the-undecidability-of-first-order-logic?rq=1). Indeed, in these sources, the word "tautology" frequently does not appear at all, and yet in case the source is a dialogue between multiple people, everyone is able to naturally carry their conversations without asking for clarification, clearly indicating that "valid" means exactly how I described it above: being a formula whose models comprise the entire space of interpretations/structures.

The question is ***not*** what valid or tautological mean. The question is how to turn "tautological" into a noun something can possess so as to be tautological, and how to turn "valid" into a noun something can be so as to be valid, etymologically related in both cases, similar to my likely non-existent suggestions in bold font above.

Comment: I'm not sure that your definition is clear enough. OED: **tautology** 5. *Logic and Philosophy.* A formula of the propositional calculus which is true under every assignment of truth or falsehood to its propositional letters, for example ‘If p and q then p’; any sentence which can be symbolized as such a formula, for example ‘If the box is small and red, then it is small’. Also more widely: **any proposition which is true because of its logical form rather than its content.** -- You mention **valid** - could you define it and distinguish it from "true"?

Comment: @Greybeard My definition of validity comes from my university professor in logic. I consulted Wikipedia, and this section seems to say basically the same thing I said:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)#Valid_formula.
So I would define "valid" as "tautological", like I wrote originally. "True" is one of the two binary values of a logical formula after giving each symbol a particular interpretation.

Comment: You'll also find this meaning of "validity" on Math.SE, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4095217/615621.

Comment: Your definitions are not quite right. A tautology is not _merely_ logically valid, it is _necessarily_ valid. Not all logically valid statements are tautologies. Saying they are synonyms wrongly conflates two categories that overlap but are not identical.

Comment: @Tom If you have a better definition, go right ahead, sir. I'm just here for the single-word request, which I'd think is unrelated to the precise definitions of these words. You don't need a definition of "beautiful" to know that "to be beautiful" means "to have beauty".

Comment: All logical and mathematical postulates, theorems, and proofs are tautologous. They're true no matter what. The point in logic and math is to create more tautologies by using known ones. This is different from science, which has data to account for; there are no tautologies in reality, only in mental descriptions.

Comment: You _do_ need to know the definition of "beauty" to know that "to be beautiful" is not interchangeable with "to look foxy," despite the considerable overlap. You are requesting a single term that belongs in two sentences that have substantially different topics, which makes confronting those topics unavoidable.

Comment: @Mew *So I would define "valid" as "tautological", like I wrote originally*. If that were true, one would wonder why there are two words for exactly the same thing. --*‘If the box is small and red, then it is small’* is true and tautological as it repeats an item from the proposition in the conclusion. It is, in layman's terms, "blindingly obvious." -- *Socrates is a man, all men are mortal, therefore Socrates is mortal.* is not tautological - there is no repetition - it has two distinct premises and a distinct conclusion - and it is truth value is 1.

Comment: "tautologicity" is the word that came to my mind even before I read that far in the question.

Comment: Don't you think "tautology" in English and in logic have clearly different uses, even if their strict meanings are the same?

In logic, tautology might well mean what you hope but in plain English, it describes a phrase containing pointless repetition of the same point.

Oxford Languages tells us that in ordinary English, tautology is the saying of the same thing twice over in different words, generally considered to be a fault of style (eg: they arrived one after the other in succession ).

That's different from logic's idea of true by necessity or by virtue of its logical form.

Answer (score 0):

This question cannot be answered, because its initial assumption that 'a synonym for [*tautological*] is that it is *logically valid*' is mistaken.

In the standard philosophical terminology, being tautological is a property of propositions or statements, while validity is a property of arguments or inferences. They are, therefore, not interchangeable.

For example,

> *p* or not-*p*

is a a tautology, a proposition that is true no matter what. It is not something of which it can be asked whether it is valid or invalid (in the technical sense of *valid* that is relevant here), because it is not an argument.

On the other hand, the following is a an example of a valid argument:

> If *p*, then *q*.
>
> *p*
>
> Therefore, *q*.

Notice that this is not one proposition, of which it could be asked whether it is a tautology. What we have here is three propositions, the last of which is entailed by the first two, taken together. None of the three is a tautology.

To every valid argument, there corresponds a tautology. For example, the validity of the above argument means that the following is a tautology:

> If ((if *p*, then *q*) and *p*), then *q*.

This a single (albeit complex) proposition, so the concept of a tautology can be applied to it. The concept of validity, however, cannot be applied to it, because it is not an argument.

All of the above is, of course, a matter of technical terminology (although of the kind that is standardly taught in introductory-logic courses). In casual communication, the terms are often used far more loosely.

Answer (score -2):

### An answer

The single word that means "is a tautology" is: "tautological." It means exactly what you want.

> The statement "either it will rain or it will not" is tautological.

- You verify that a statement is valid by checking its validity, meaning it **is logically consistent**.
- You verify that a statement is tautological by checking whether **its truth status is contingent**, meaning it is a tautology.

There is no one term that fits in both places. Let's consider why.

#### Validity, soundness, and contingency

Given an expression or proposition or argument, we might say:

- it is logically valid
- it is logically sound
- it is necessarily true (or necessarily false)

**Validity** is concerned entirely with the form or structure of the expression, and it does not care at all about truth or falsity:

> an argument is valid if and only if it takes a form that makes it impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion nevertheless to be false
> -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic))

Here's an example of an invalid argument:

1. Socrates is a man
2. I love donuts
3. Therefore, Socrates is mortal

All three of those statements may be true, but the truth of statement #3 cannot be proved based on the first two statements. (Because this example does not provide a definition of "mortal.")

Here's a valid argument:

1. Socrates is a wizard
2. Wizards can transform lazy students into donuts
3. Therefore, Socrates can turn lazy students into donuts

This is a fantasy, but it is *not* nonsense. The conclusion *does* flow directly from the premises, which means that if statements #1 and #2 turn out to be true, then statement #3 must be true also.

**Soundness** is the next "layer" of scrutiny: an argument is sound if and only if it is both valid *and also true*:

> an argument is sound if it is both valid in form and its premises are true
> -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness)

Both of my previous examples are unsound, although the second example is at least valid.

**Contingency**, or being contingent, is to depend on something beyond pure logic for one's truth-value. A contingent fact is something about the world that *could* be different.

Example: Bill Murray was offered the role of Han Solo but turned it down. He could have chosen to accept it. Han Solo being played by Harrison Ford is a contingent fact: it could have been otherwise. If you want to make (or evaluate) an argument that depends on who played Han Solo, you must actually go into the world and learn some facts. It is *a posteriori* rather than *a priori*.

**Tautologies** are statements or arguments whose truth or falsity depends on no factors external to themselves.

- Either it will rain or it will not.

Necessarily true. It doesn't matter what "rain" even *means*.

- Either it will flnargn-blargl or it will not.

*Still* necessarily true.

- Socrates is rain.

Necessarily false (with the implied premises that Socrates is a human and rain is precipitation).

Often if an argument is tautological, it's because it only makes assertions about what our words mean. That is, they ultimately just restate the definitions of terms we already know (which is sometimes a useful exercise).

Comment: Once again, I want to refer you to the usage of "valid" and "validity" in computer science as per https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612681/validity-undecidable-in-first-order-logic. It wouldn't make sense for someone to write "a statement whose negation is valid" if it was merely about syntax, for example. In any case: you left out "a" in front of the first ellipsis, and I need single-word completions anyway.

Comment: You're ignoring the larger point that there is no single word that fits into the two slots that you mistakenly believe should both accept a single word. And I stand by the definitions of validity and soundness that I cited, which are the same ones I was taught in school.